# Get current block number in `paritytech/parity`

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

Parity UI displays current block number at the bottom, but if UI is not enabled, then how do we find the current block number?

Is there a way to find current block number

- using JSONRPC ?
- Is it stored somewhere in basepath?

**Note:** If anyone can find proper tags, please update it! Currently there is no tag for `parity`.

Comment: FYI, there are many more ethereum-specific tags over at ethereum.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the latest block number over rpc by calling the 'eth_blockNumber' method.

From the [JSON RPC docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_blocknumber):

> Returns the number of most recent block.
>
> ```
> // Request
> curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":83}'
>
> // Result
> {
>   "id":83,
>   "jsonrpc": "2.0",
>   "result": "0x4b7" // 1207
> }
> ```

---

There are other, higher level APIs that you might be interested in, like [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) or [web3.py](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html). They both allow you to use `web3.eth.blockNumber` to get the latest block number, and generally work in native types rather than hex strings.

Comment: `| grep -oh "\w*0x\w*"` would get only block number. Entire command would be ``echo$((`curl --data '{"method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545 | grep -oh "\w*0x\w*"`))``

Answer (score 2):

Using the answer posted by @carver I was able to get only the current block number in decimal form, my RPC port is 8545(default):

```
echo $((`curl --data '{"method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545 | grep -oh "\w*0x\w*"`))
```